# Keep iPad always on and locked to one app. In >iOS 12

Tags: ios, ipad, sleep-wake

Ive got an iPad mini 4 in a wall mount like this [here.](https://www.wall-smart.com/invisible-mount-for-ipad-mini4.html)

I want to set the iPad screen to be constantly on, locked to one app. Prior to iOS 12 i was able to do this by A) setting the sleep setting to "never" and B) putting the iPad into guided access mode to lock it into one app. But since the release of iOS 12 the iPad will only stay on for about 30 minutes, with settings A) and B). If i just set the iPad to setting A) it will stay on indefinitely, but i cant lock the screen to a single app. For more info on this issue, see this thread [here.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/340248/set-ios-device-into-kiosk-mode-and-get-the-screen-not-to-sleep/344193#344193)

Is there another way to lock an iPad to a single app, whilst at the same time keeping the screen on indefinitely ? Perhaps through adopting the iPad into MDM mode or developer mode ?

Comment: this should work, see https://learninginhand.com/blog/limit-an-ios-device-to-running-a-single-app.html

Comment: @DaniilManokhin , unfortunately that is the technique i was using previously but it has stopped working in iOS 12. In iOS 11 and lower it worked great.

Comment: have you tried setting it up again?

Comment: @DaniilManokhin when you say setting it up again, what do you mean exactly ? Eg. wipe iPad and restart from scratch ? If so no. I have disabled guided access and re set guided access but the problem persists. The iPad came with iOS 12 so i was never able to test it on this particular model. But i have set it up a few times before on iOS 11 devices on other projects and it worked fine. I have also tested it on my personal iPad which shipped with iOS 11 and i upgraded to iOS 12 manually and the guided access solution didnt work.

Comment: cant you just keep it on one app and set auto lock to never

Comment: did my answer help?

Comment: @DaniilManokhin i tried in on one iPad over the weekend, but didnt get it working, im going to get another ipad to test it on

Comment: ok, hope it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen several people with the same issue. Assuming you upgraded the iPad with guided access enabled follow these steps:

> I have found that if Guided access was enabled prior to the upgrade it
>   might reset in this process.
>
> 1. Turn off Guided Access in Accessibility / Settings.
> 2. Hard reboot.  (Hold Home and Lock buttons for 7 seconds)
> 3. Turn on Guided Access in Accessibility / Settings.  Reset Passcode.

---

From [Kiosk:](https://docs.kioskproapp.com/article/899-ios-12-with-guided-access-causing-kiosk-pro-to-sleep)

> iOS 12.1.1 has been released and includes a fix to this issue, but requires a change to a new setting introduced in this release to prevent the screen from sleeping: General > Accessibility > Guided Access > Mirror Display Auto-Lock > ON.

to update your device, go to Settings -> General -> Software Update

Comment: iOS 12.1.13 was released a few days ago.

Comment: @IconDaemon I know, and?

Comment: Your answer cites Kiosk: "iOS 12.1.1 has been released ..." I was merely mentioning that there is a new release available, which some folks may not be aware of. That's all.

Comment: @IconDaemon oh i see